# how to add php variable(s)/arrays in Javascript function ( in jsGrid({ controller }) )

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, jsgrid

I am using http://js-grid.com for my php application. I choose this library for inline edit/update/add/delete. Now I want to view `$variables` or `$array` data(s) which will come from database. Here is the script

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
            pageButtonCount: 5,
            deleteConfirm: "Do you really want to delete the client?",
            controller: db,
            fields: [
                { name: "Name", type: "text", width: 150 },
                { name: "Age", type: "number", width: 50 },
                { type: "control" }
            ]
        });

    });
</script>
```

in above code I got a property called `controller` which is rendering `db (data)`. `db` is coming from a file `db.js`. The file looks as below:

```
(function() {
var db = {
    loadData: function(filter) {
        return $.grep(this.clients, function(client) {
            return (!filter.Name || client.Name.indexOf(filter.Name) > -1)
                && (!filter.Age || client.Age === filter.Age)
                && (!filter.Address || client.Address.indexOf(filter.Address) > -1)
                && (!filter.Country || client.Country === filter.Country)
                && (filter.Married === undefined || client.Married === filter.Married);
        });
    },
    insertItem: function(insertingClient) {
        this.clients.push(insertingClient);
    },
    updateItem: function(updatingClient) { },
    deleteItem: function(deletingClient) {
        var clientIndex = $.inArray(deletingClient, this.clients);
        this.clients.splice(clientIndex, 1);
    }
};

window.db = db;

db.countries = [
    { Name: "", Id: 0 },
    { Name: "United States", Id: 1 },
];

db.clients = [
    {
        "Name": "Otto Clay",
        "Age": 61,
    },
    {
        "Name": "Connor Johnston",
        "Age": 73,
    }
];

}());
```

Also I followed the github docs https://github.com/tabalinas/jsgrid-php. But I can not figure out that how do I place my `php $variable or $array` in my views as well as `javaScripts`.

*What I want to :* 
I want to call `$array` into the section of javaScripts as `controller : db`.

*Error:* 
When I use `controller: <?php echo $array; ?>', its returning null cause I can not call as they called as default from`db.js`

Please help me out that how may I call `php $variable or $array` instead of `controller: db` in `javaScript`
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: please do not add php variables in javascript, besides being ugly is such bad practice, add a method that returns json to the browser instead

Comment: @jycr753 :: I did not get you. Would you please like to guide me little more ? By the way I am working in Laravel 5.1 :: I have a method in controller to prepare the array or variable then I send to views

Comment: you are doing laravel so that is really easy, just create a new router that will call the controller that will generate the data that you need, in the controller call method that return the data from models, I guess is a user model? is really simple to do

Comment: @jycr753 :: Yes it is user model. and I got your point. But how may I call the `route` into view  as returning `$array or $data`   ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `controller` option defines behavior, you cannot put static data there. 
But there is an option [data](http://js-grid.com/docs/#data) where you can put static values (like in your example from php).

Another option for you is to define `controller.loadData`:

```
controller: {
    loadData: function() {
        return $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/clients/"
        });
    },
```

and on the server you serve the requested information

```
switch($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]) {
    case "GET":
        $result = $clients->getAll();
        break;
    ...
}

header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode($result);
```

You can find the implementation in the [jsgrid-php repo](https://github.com/tabalinas/jsgrid-php).

Comment: :: Thank you. Let me check them all into my system.